# How to test a spring controller method by using MockMvc?

Tags: spring, junit, integration-testing

I'm using spring 3.2.0 and junit 4

This is my controller method which I need to test

```
@RequestMapping(value="Home")
public ModelAndView returnHome(){

return new ModelAndView("Home");    
}
```

spring-servlet config is:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.poc" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

This is my test class :

```
public class TestController {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new CController()).setViewResolvers(
            viewResolver).build();
}

@Test
public void CControllerTest() throws Exception {
    ......
    ......      
}
```

}

How can I test this method with MockMvc ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use your applications dispatcher servlet xml using the following annoations.  The following example is hitting a controller with the path /mysessiontest setting some session attributes and expecting a certain view to be returned:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:springDispatcher-servlet.xml" })

public class MySessionControllerTest {

    @Autowired WebApplicationContext wac; 
    @Autowired MockHttpSession session;
    @Autowired MockHttpServletRequest request;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAccount() throws Exception {
        UserDomain user = new UserDomain();
        user.setFirstName("johnny");

        session.setAttribute("sessionParm",user);
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/mysessiontest").session(session)
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("test"));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mnauel Qunones: i tried to run test case with your instruction. but its failed to run. all springframe work jar are same version (3.2.0).               .java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 get cannot be resolved to a variable
 The method status() is undefined for the type Test1
 The method view() is undefined for the type Test1

 at com.dummy.poc.Test1.homeTest(Test1.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

Comment: I will add the imports needed to my sample.

Comment: compiler dosen't recognize get , saying get cannot be resolved to a variable . At this line : this.mockMvc.perform(get / "Home").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("Home"));

Comment: Have you added the static imports that I added to my answer?  That should resolve your compilation problems.

Comment: @Manel Quinones. thank you.its working fine ,got green on Junit Console.

Comment: is this possible to test the same controller method with junit?

Comment: @ManuelQuinones is it possible to add request value to mockmvc

Comment: @ManuelQuinones. I have @RequestParam("userName") String userName in my controller by using the above method how would i add request param to test method

Comment: You literally saved me an entire night of peaceful sleep. Thanks much.