# How to test spring RESTful MVC controller methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've got simple Spring MVC project created in Spring Tool Suite IDE, so project's structure is

[image]

I need to test my controller methods, for example

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/references/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody GAReference getReference(@PathVariable("id") int id) { 
        return server.getReference(id);
    }
```

server is an interface, it has implementation (ServerTestImpl), and there is a ServerTestImpl bean stored in MainControllerContext.xml.

I want my test class to look like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563489/how-to-test-a-spring-controller-method-by-using-mockmvc), but I don't have springDispatcher-servlet.xml in my project structure.
So, I think it might be like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/MainControllerContext.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MainControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc ;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private ServerTestImpl server;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).dispatchOptions(true).build();
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetReference() {    
         try {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/references/5"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", is(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].description", is("Lorem ipsum")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].title", is("Foo")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].id", is(2)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].description", is("Lorem ipsum")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].title", is("Bar")));      
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

}
```

How can I test my controller with this project structure?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a question ?

Comment: Now there is, thanks for your remark.

Comment: Unit test the methods? Or test the Spring annotations? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippet on setup

> @Before
>       public void setUp($basecontroller controllerobj)
>   { this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standAloneSetup(controllerobj).dispatchOptions(true).build();
>   }

$basecontroller = base controller of the controllers residing in the same package as the other controllers.