# Nullpointer on HttpServletResponse response using SpringFramework Test and Mockito

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mockito, spring-test

I am testing my Spring @RestController using a standalone setup, and mocking some autowired beans using mockito, so far all my tests have been successful, until i try to test this restservice:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/{someId}/other/someagain", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public FileSystemResource downloadInvoiceQuery(@PathVariable Long someId,
        @RequestBody SomeClass request, HttpServletResponse response) {
.
.
.
mockedBean.method("object1","object2");
response.setHeader("some headers");
}
```

Using this test:

```
when(mockedBean.method(any(), any())).thenReturn(null);

mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/some/{someId}/other/someagain", 1L)
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content("{}")).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
```

I am getting a Nullpointer when the setHeaders method is called over the HttpServletResponse object in the Controller. I cant figure it out how to inject or pass that response object to avoid the null pointer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When testing spring mvc controllers I would always use MockMvc

See here for an example: 
[How to test a spring controller method by using MockMvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563489/how-to-test-a-spring-controller-method-by-using-mockmvc)

The documentation can be found here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-framework

Here is an example from the documentation using the standalone setup:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("test-servlet-context.xml")
public class ExampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAccount() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/accounts/1").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Lee"));
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not using stand alone setup : MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup, but maybe using this setup i will avoid the Response null pointer.

Comment: True - thanks for the hint - but in the case described both variants should do - setting up a standalone context is done like this `this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new AccountController()).build();`

Comment: I have my configuration setted properly in an stand alone way, my Controller exposes many url's and i test them all in a successfully way, but the method i'm showing is the only one that fails for the null pointer in the response object.

Comment: I have a similar use case and it does not work either. How is it possible to inject or mock the response into the controllers method?