# Do I need to create a new MockMvc for each test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, mockmvc

I’m attempting to add [Cucumber](http://cukes.info) to my Spring Web MVC project which is already using spring-test and JUnit. The non-Cucumber integration tests I’ve already written have the WebApplicationContext autowired in, then created a `MockMvc` for each test. The [Cucumber example](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/spring-txn/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/spring/txn/SeeMessagesStepdefs.java) I’m trying to work from injects a `MockMvc` once for the lifetime of the step definition class.

The [API docs for MockMVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) don’t give any guidance on how calling `perform` modifies a `MockMvc` instance, and whether it’s acceptable to reuse a `MockMvc` instance for multiple tests. I also wasn’t able to find a definite answer in the [reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/).

What is the contract with `MockMvc`? Should I be creating a new one for each test?

Comment: In your test, create `@Before` and initialize `mockmvc`. Look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14566090/3710490](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14566090/3710490)

Comment: Thank you, @Valijon; that’s precisely how I’m doing it in my existing JUnit tests. However, the example I cite does it a different way, and I would like to know if the contract for `MockMvc` supports that other way of doing things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the instance variables of `MockMvc` and you may be able to deduce a answer.

```
static String MVC_RESULT_ATTRIBUTE = MockMvc.class.getName().concat(".MVC_RESULT_ATTRIBUTE");

private final TestDispatcherServlet servlet;

private final Filter[] filters;

private final ServletContext servletContext;

private RequestBuilder defaultRequestBuilder;

private List<ResultMatcher> defaultResultMatchers = new ArrayList<ResultMatcher>();

private List<ResultHandler> defaultResultHandlers = new ArrayList<ResultHandler>();
```

Instance/class variables `MVC_RESULT_ATTRIBUTE` and `TestDispatcherServlet` are thread-safe and `filters` and `servletContext` are only set during initialization.
`filters` and `servletContext` should be thread-safe and stateless, too. `defaultRequestBuilder`, `defaultResultMatchers` and `defaultResultHandlers` have a setter method. From a technical point of view `MockMvc` is not thread-safe and shouldn't be reused. These setters are package private and a `MockMvc` instance can be acquired only through `MockMvcBuilders`. Hence you can't manipulte a `MockMvc` instance afterwards so that it is actually resuable across multiple tests.

Answer (score 3):

MockMvc can be created once and used for any number of requests.