# when i pass json object it store null values in mongodb using DTO

Tags: json, mongodb, rest, spring-boot, dto

visit link https://github.com/ashishklae/postjob

when i post the Json object it store all null values in mongodb but when i update it it works i am using  DTO pattern and i think my create method in my postjob service implemention is wrong some logic is missing please help.

code of postjobserviceImplementation

```
package postjob.model;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

@Service
public class PostJobServiceImp  implements PostJobService {

@Autowired
private final PostJobRepository repository;

@Autowired
 public PostJobServiceImp(PostJobRepository repository) {
   this.repository = repository;
}

@Override
public PostJobDTO create(PostJobDTO pj) {

  PostJob postj = new PostJob();
  repository.save(postj);
 return convertToDTO(postj);

}


@Override
public PostJobDTO update(PostJobDTO UID) {
    PostJob updated = findpostJobById(UID.getId());
    updated.update(UID.getUserid(), UID.getSummary(),UID.getCategory(),UID.getSubCategory(),UID.getState(), UID.getPrivate(), UID.getBudget(),UID.getCity(),UID.getDuration(),UID.getINR(), UID.getReferenceDocs(), UID.getStatus(), UID.getDateTimeOfPost(), UID.getDescription(), UID.getLocation());
    updated = repository.save(updated);
    return convertToDTO(updated);
 }

 @Override
 public List<PostJobDTO> findAll() {
    List<PostJob> postJobEntries = repository.findAll();
    return convertToDTOs(postJobEntries);
 }

  private List<PostJobDTO> convertToDTOs(List<PostJob> models) {
        return models.stream()
                .map(this::convertToDTO)
                .collect(toList());
    }

  @Override
    public PostJobDTO findById(String id) {
        PostJob job = findpostJobById(id);
        return convertToDTO(job);
    }

 private PostJob findpostJobById(String id) {
    Optional<PostJob> result = repository.findOne(id);
    return result.orElseThrow(() -> new  PostJobNotFoundException(id));
 }


  private PostJobDTO convertToDTO(PostJob model) {
     PostJobDTO dto = new PostJobDTO();

        dto.setUserid(model.getUserid());
        dto.setSummary(model.getSummary());
        dto.setCategory(model.getCategory());
        dto.setSubCategory(model.getSubCategory());
        dto.setDescription(model.getDescription());
        dto.setReferenceDocs(model.getReferenceDocs());
        dto.setBudget(model.getBudget());
        dto.setINR(model.getINR());
        dto.setLocation(model.getLocation());
        dto.setCity(model.getCity());
        dto.setState(model.getState());
        dto.setDuration(model.getDuration());
        dto.setDateTimeOfPost(model.getDateTimeOfPost());
        dto.setStatus(model.getStatus());
        dto.setPrivate(model.getPrivate());

        return dto;
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your method:

```
@Override
public PostJobDTO create(PostJobDTO pj) {

  PostJob postj = new PostJob();
  repository.save(postj);
  return convertToDTO(postj);
}
```

I think you want to store the passed PostJobDTO `pj` in your database, don't you?

But what you do is: you completely ignore `pj` and create a new (empty) PostJob and save this one.

Solution:

create a copy constructor for PostJob which takes an PostJobDTO and sets the values of the dto to his own fields.

=>

```
@Override
public PostJobDTO create(PostJobDTO pj) {

  PostJob postj = repository.save(new PostJob(pj));
  return convertToDTO(postj);
}
```

you can do it via a `PostJob convertToEnity(PostJobDTO pj)`, too.

=>

```
@Override
public PostJobDTO create(PostJobDTO pj) {

  PostJob postj = repository.save(convertToEntity(pj));
  return convertToDTO(postj);
}
```

Comment: yes,want to store the passed PostJobDTO pj in your database,

Comment: if the provided answer fit your needs, accept it ;) if not let me now what's missing

Comment: i have created a copy constructor for PostJob which takes an PostJobDTO .

Comment: but  how to sets the values of the dto to his own fields.?

Comment: i forked your repo and created a pull request. just merge it

Comment: i got the second method but how to get with first method i.e copy constructor https://github.com/ashishklae/postjob/tree/master/postJob

Comment: i already did and created a pull request https://github.com/ashishklae/postjob/pull/1

Comment: 1 more issue i want to write junit .on controller can u help

Comment: So the question is solved? Would be nice if you accept it as the answer. For your other question have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14566090/2576531