# How to instantiate seesion before unit testing execution so that autowired session in service class creates bean corectly?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, session, junit

How to instantiate seesion before unit testing execution so that autowired session in service class creates bean correctly ?

My test uses some methods from a service class. This service class method uses an autowired session. The point is that i don't know how to create/inject into the session in the test (or before it) so that the session bean creates correctly in the service with the details i set beforehand.

The session class looks like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserSession {
 Long idUser;
 //...other 

 //geters and seters
}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
public class MyTestClass{

 @Autowired
 private UserSession session;

 @Autowired
 private MyServiceClass myServiceClass;

   @Test
   public void myTestMethod() {
   ....
   //This is where i wanted to set some session detailes
   //Something like this:
   session.setUserRolls(...);


   myServiceClass.myServiceMethod();

   }
}
```

In my service class i have something like this:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceClass{

@Autowired
private UserSession session;


private void myServiceMethod(){
 ....
 List <UserRol> rolls = session.getUserRolls();
 //in this case i want to retrieve user rolls from session object
 //
 //now i get an error in my current implementation that looks like this
 //Error: no Scope registered for scope name "session"
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I would do it with Mockito [link](http://mockito.org) if there are no other reasons why you are using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.

Comment: @azl I can't relay change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you should do is to put @WebAppConfiguration before your test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyTestClass{
......
}
```

Inside the class you should inject your session class using @autowired exactly like you did.
After that inside your test, before you call your service function, you can set your session details using setters. The details will be visible inside your service so everything should work just fine.
The presence of @WebAppConfiguration on your test class instructs the TestContext framework (TCF) that a WebApplicationContext (WAC) should be loaded for your tests, so that will give you session scoped beans.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO trying to autowire a session scoped bean in a unit test is bad design. Normal unit testing should be possible by mocking the bean. With mock framework like [mockito](http://mockito.org), you can even control that methods have been called with the expected parameters.

If you need actual interaction with that bean - but it is now an integration test - you should manually build the bean the way it should look like in the use case you are testing, and manually inject it into the service class you are testing.

Anyway, having dependencies on a session scoped bean (isn't it controller of view layer?) inside a service bean (should be service layer) smells. It may be a perfectly correct design, but you really should think twice about that, mainly if it is now hard to test.

Don't forget: test should remain as simple as possible. If they cannot, look again at your general design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Spring MockMVC framework and add a @WebAppConfiguration, that will give you session scoped beans.

Look at this example [How to test a spring controller method by using MockMvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563489/how-to-test-a-spring-controller-method-by-using-mockmvc)